# Computer doesn't recognize USB device

Tags: usb, usb-drive, eject

I am trying to use an iPod with Rhythmbox in Ubuntu 12.04.  I was going to post this as an iPod problem, but it looks like it is bigger than that.

When I plug in the iPod in my computer, it reads the files in it but doesn't treat it like a device.  That is to say that I can see the folder named usb0 in the desktop and find iPod files in it, still in a rudimentary fashion.

Moreover, there is no option for me to "Safely Remove" the device; and if I click to unmount it, I get a message about not being root user.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First to mount your ipod :

```
sudo apt-get install ifuse libimobiledevice-utils

idevicepair unpair (to unpair)

 idevicepair pair (to pair)
```

Second to unmount use sudo before ur command and enter your password

Comment: The computer says "no device found, is it plugged in?"
It is certainly plugged in, but the computer isn't recognizing it.

Comment: About unmounting, I only know how to do it from the desktop.  Do you have a reference where I can learn about the commands to unmount it?

Comment: check this dear https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount